# Managed Metadata is reporting errors, how can I start it again?

Tags: permissions, managed-metadata

When I try to manage the managed metadata service I get "The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator. "

I've just installed SP1.

I get this in the Event Log:

"The Managed Metadata Service 'Metadata Service Application Proxy' is inaccessible. The web application does not have sufficient permissions."

Done lots of Googling, restarted a few times, fooled with permissions, the lot and nothing seems to make a difference.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you follow these instructions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383250.aspx to make sure that the app pool account has the correct permissions?

Comment: Yes, in fact I've added 'all authenticated users' with full permission but it doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is an answer that will help anyone else, but, after fooling with the application permissions on the Manage Service Applications page, I decided to change the App Pool (as it the existing one had a GUID for a name, I thought perhaps removing spaces or something may give it a human-readable one.  No, as it turns out) and the new app pool apparently works.  I also had the service stopped when I did this and restarted it from the Manage Services on Server page.